# Angularjs странно работает

Tags: angularjs

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kLL3wdee/)

```
<input ng-model="showSpecial2" type="checkbox" />
<div ng-show="showSpecial2" id="special2">
   first
</div>

<input ng-model="showSpecial" type="checkbox" />
<div ng-show=”showSpecial” id="special">
   second
</div>
```

В чем разница между 1 и 2 и почему один работает, а другой нет

Comment: У вас скобки неправильные во втором варианте. `”` а надо `"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неправильные скобки во втором блоке. Вместо `"` у вас `”`
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kLL3wdee/1/)

```
<input ng-model="showSpecial1" type="checkbox" />
<div ng-show="showSpecial1" id="special1">
first
</div>
<input ng-model="showSpecial2" type="checkbox" />
<div ng-show="showSpecial2" id="special2">
last
</div>
```

Comment: а в чем была ошибка?

Comment: вместо " у вас было ”

Comment: @Abmin, пояснение должно быть непосредственно в ответе

Comment: @Grundy, исправил